# What does darkModeSupport actually do in Electron-Builder?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

Electron-Builder indicates this option exists, but does not give sufficient clarification about what it does. For macOS builds:

> [`darkModeSupport`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/mac.html) = `false` Boolean - Whether a dark mode is supported. If your app does have a dark mode, you can make your app follow the system-wide dark mode setting.

But what does it ***actually do?*** Because this is not anywhere near enough to make an app support dark mode, or even adhere to dark mode automatically - both of which would be achieved with Electron's [`nativeTheme`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/native-theme#nativethemethemesource) module.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

It sets `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` to NO. I found this by searching the code: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aelectron-userland%2Felectron-builder%20NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance&type=code

Here's Apple's documentation on the option: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app

> If you build your app against an earlier SDK but still want to support Dark Mode, include the NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance key (with a value of NO) in your app's Info.plist file. Do so only if your app's appearance looks correct when running in macOS 10.14 and later with Dark Mode enabled.

It doesn't look like it matters if building against macOS 10.14 or later.